# Two Errors trying to include .php file: Warning: require(...) AND Fatal error: require() ... (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

Tags: php, include, pear, require

Here is the first error:

```
Warning: require(/hb/includes/constants.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp2\www\hb\includes\connection.php on line 2
```

And the second error that immediately follows:

```
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/hb/includes/constants.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp2\www\hb\includes\connection.php on line 2
```

Here is the line that it doesn't like:

```
require("/hb/includes/constants.php");
```

I did install a new version of WAMP, but I know the directories/files are fine and the code worked previously and on another server.  It seems like none of my require()'s are working anymore.  I tried looking around and some suggested to others that they edit their php.ini, but I don't know what directory I would point to - if you can't tell I'm pretty noobish regarding all things server related.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, are your really -- really ! --  sure that the file `/hb/includes/constants.php`, that your are trying to include, exists ?

Considering that the path you requested begins with a `/`, it looks like you're using an absolute path... that looks like an UNIX path, but you are on a Windows server...

If it exists, and PHP still cannot include it, check :

- that it is readable by your webserver (including the directories) -- I'm thinking about UNIX permissions
- that there is no [**`open_basedir`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) restriction that would prevent PHP from accessing those files.

BTW, having a warning and a fatal error is the behavior that's to be expected when using [`require`][2] : the warning is normal *(it comes from `include`)* ; and the fatal error is the difference between `include` and `require`.

Comment: I get the same result with and without the slash, it does exist.  I checked for the open_basedir in my php.ini and it was commented out.

Comment: OK. Are you really sure the file exists, and that PHP can find it, using the `include_path` ? Remember that you have `.` *(the "current directory")* in your `include_path`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, here is the dir from the file's properties dialog: C:\wamp2\www\hb\includes and here is the URL that I can use to hit the file: http://localhost/hb/includes/constants.php.

Comment: it was an issue with where the files were in relation to my server's root, thanks for the help... i'm just stupid :P.